# VBA Loop to fill out a table using DataBodyRange.Formula overrides previous row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-tables

I have 2 tables in 2 different workbooks. Example:

Table 1:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 |

I am trying to fill out a second table with a links to the first table. What I am looking to get:
Table 2:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| =link to table 1(1,1) | link to table 1(1,2) | link to table 1(1,3) | link to table 1(1,4) |
| =link to table 1(2,1) | link to table 1(2,2) | link to table 1(2,3) | link to table 1(2,4) |
| =link to table 1(3,1) | link to table 1(3,2) | link to table 1(3,3) | link to table 1(3,4) |
| =link to table 1(4,1) | link to table 1(4,2) | link to table 1(4,3) | link to table 1(4,4) |

The part of my code:

```
for i=1 to RowCount 'table1

 Dest_row = DestTbl.ListRows.Count  
 Dest_column= DestTbl.Range.Columns.Count 
 Source_Column=1
   
      for column=1 to Dest_column
    
      Cell_addr=cells(i,Source_Column).address

      table2.DataBodyRange(Dest_row,Column).Formula= "='[" & File_path & "]Sheet1'!" & Cell_addr

      Source_Column= Source_Column+1

      Next
Table2.listrows.add
Next
```

Instead of desired result in table 2 I get the following table:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| =link to table 1(4,1) | link to table 1(4,2) | link to table 1(4,3) | link to table 1(4,4) |
| =link to table 1(4,1) | link to table 1(4,2) | link to table 1(4,3) | link to table 1(4,4) |
| =link to table 1(4,1) | link to table 1(4,2) | link to table 1(4,3) | link to table 1(4,4) |
| =link to table 1(4,1) | link to table 1(4,2) | link to table 1(4,3) | link to table 1(4,4) |

While the loop runs I can see that initially VBA inserts the correct link in a row, but as soon as loop goes to the second row, first row overrides with information from the second row. Then when the loop goes to 3rd row, first 2 rows changes to the link in 3rd row.

I have been trying to figure it out for a week now, so I tried to insert a cell address from the first table to the second table just to see if the loop works correctly. It does, but when I add "=" the last row overrides all the previous rows. I am completely lost. Anyone knows what could be an issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you no need a loop in this case:

```
Sub FillTable2()
    Dim Table1 As ListObject, Table2 As ListObject
    ' dummy data; the source workbook needs to be open
    File_path = "source.xlsx"
    Set Table1 = Workbooks(File_path).Sheets(1).ListObjects(1)  'get the source table
    Set Table2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1)  'get the destination table
    
    If Not Table2.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then Table2.DataBodyRange.Delete ' clear the destination table
    'make the formula with the **external** relative address of the first cell in the Table1.DataBodyRange
    frm = "=" & Table1.DataBodyRange(1).Address(external:=True, rowabsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
    'insert formula to the whole target range; the table size will be automatically the size of the table will be automatically enlarged if necessary
    Table2.InsertRowRange(1).Resize(Table1.ListRows.Count, Table1.ListColumns.Count).Formula = frm
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need a loop because not all the rows from table 1 are need to be linked. My question is why after adding "=" into the formula, the last row in the Table 2 overrides all the previously linked rows.  So basically all the rows are being linked to the last entered row.

Comment: I replaced my code with this line in loop and now it works. Thank you!
frm = "=" & Table1.DataBodyRange(1).Address(external:=True, rowabsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)

Answer (score 0):

### New answer

Try replacing this line:

```
table2.DataBodyRange(Dest_row,Column).Formula= "='[" & File_path & "]Sheet1'!" & Cell_addr
```

With:

```
table2.DataBodyRange(i,Column).Formula= "='[" & File_path & "]Sheet1'!" & Cell_addr
```

### Old answer

(Kept because it is taking me a bit of effort to work out what part is not working for you.)

Try this:

In your fourth line:

```
 Source_Column=1
```

Change to

```
Source_Column = i
```

Or if that is not your issue, check your variable called `column` in the inner loop is initiated at the top, then used with title case as `Column`, if you make these either both `Columnn` or both `column`, what happens then.